# One 1 minute (mathematica)

Tags: prime-numbers, mathematica-online

I wanna evaluate how large prime numbers my computer work at most 60 seconds. Of course, I can evalutate this manaully e.g. by trying different values.
However, can I do this differently, e.g. by setting the time?

Comment: Hi! Please, take the time to read your question and provide us with a minimum reproducible example. As it is currently written you are generating a random prime in the range `{10^2000, 10^2000}`. Also - what is your end goal? Generating prime numbers? Filtering them afterwards?

Comment: Hi, sorry it should be '''{10^1999, 10^2000}'''.

Comment: My end goal is that I wanna have the maximum digit prime I could generate in 60 seconds. As of right now, I can only get the time for a given prime. I wanna have a function that works in the opposite way.

Comment: So I wanna set the time manually, e.g.60 second or 80 seconds and then generate  maximum digit prime based on this time.

Comment: It produces `{9.45313, \
6874090616771610210074487399211060171147764570196238070783173836677958\
1619995425908424621945207150352924177002190160746774878511809371120288\
910835110915978986241...}` on my comp.

Comment: _maximum digit prime based on this time_ you do realize this might be highly variable in timing and not produce consistently the same prime for a chosen execution time?

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want. You can change the argument of `PrimeQ` based on the granularity you are looking for VS the time you want to spend. `TimeConstrainted` aborts if the computation takes more than 60 seconds, `CheckAbort` returns `Print[n]` if `PrimeQ` took more than 60 seconds.

```
n = 10;
While[Not@CheckAbort[TimeConstrained[PrimeQ[10^(100*n) + 1], 60]
  , Print[n]], n++]
```

Returns `n=176` for 10 seconds and `n=304` for 60 seconds on my laptop.

You can check: `PrimeQ[10^(100*304) + 1] // AbsoluteTiming` returns 68 seconds (and `False`). If you are looking specifically for primes, you can adapt the above code.